# htaccess - how to allow other files to be accessed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have the following htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/index.php?pg=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

### What's working?

http://site/v2/test 
-> goes to http://site/v2/index.php?pg=test

### What's not working?

If I want to load css or zip files.. 
`http://site/v2/_downloads/download.zip`
it goes to:
`http://site/v2/index.php?pg=_downloads/download.zip`

But I'd like to go to the actual page
Same for the css
For some reason it loads:
`http://site/v2/index.php?pg=_css/style.css`
instead of `http://site/v2/_css/style.css`

What did I do wrong? Just can't seem to see it..

Comment: does `http://site/v2/_css/style.css` exist?

Comment: @Martin; all files do exist, yes

Comment: @Martin; thanks for the link, it helped me in the good direction

Comment: So the conditions to check whether it’s an existing file or directory, appear not to be working correctly. Can you try `REQUEST_URI` instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME` in both, and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @CBroe This worked as well:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.bat|\.zip|\.rar|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
`
If I changed the second condition, it returned a 500 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.bat|\.zip|\.rar|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/index.php?pg=$1 [L]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ v2/index.php?pg=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, this simply works around the issue.

Comment: The problem is that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should cause the rewrite to abort if the file exists, but this doesn't appear to be occuring for your files.

Comment: No exactly, that's why I don't get it not working correctly..